# Преобразование json файла в python словарь

Tags: python, json

Есть json следующего типа: [{},{},{}]
То есть внутри несколько словарей
Можно ли такой объект сразу перевести в один словарей без итераций в нем, каким нибудь одним методом?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `json.loads(<строка>)` модуля "json" вернет словарь.

Пример использования:

```
>>> import json
>>> x = '[{"a":1, "b":2},{"a":3, "b":4},{"a":5, "b":6}]'
>>> data = json.loads(x)
>>> print (data)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
>>> print (data[0])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> print (data[1])
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Также можно использовать метод `json.load(<файл>)`. Он также вернет словарь:

```
>>> import json
>>> file = open("file.json")
>>> data = json.load(file)
>>> print(data)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]
>>> print(data[0])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>>
```